# Program that counts the occurrence of each word given by a text file which path is on arguments doesn't work

Tags: c, string, count

edit: I found strtok doenst get the string corrects for some reason how can i fix that?

I have this exercise which states that I must find the occurrence of each word and display it with the word next to it using `calloc` (for example for the word "World" that is found 2 times in the text will display like this: World 2).My algorithm doesn't work the output is nonsense for example: `"1,78c1,78"`

This is my algorithm where I don't know what wrong with it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

   FILE *file=fopen(argv[1],"r");
   if(!file) {
  perror("File opening failed");
  return 1;
}
   int size = 1024;
   int *wordcount = calloc(size, sizeof(int));
   
   char **words = calloc(size, sizeof(char*));
   char line[1024];
   int p=0;
   int i=0;
     while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL) {
        char *word = strtok(line, " ");
        while (word != NULL) {
            for (int j=0;j<i;j++){
                if (strcmp(words[j],word)==0){
                    p=1;
                    wordcount[j]++;
                    break;
                } 
            }
            if (p==0){
              words[i]=strdup(word);
              wordcount[i]++;
              i++;
            }
            p=0;
            word = strtok(NULL, " ");
        
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (words[i] != NULL) {
            printf("%s %d", words[i], wordcount[i]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

     fclose(file);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (words[i] != NULL) {
            free(words[i]);
        }
    }
    free(words);
    free(wordcount);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is one of the inputs I have been given that I have to run through tests.

```
Computer science is the study of computation, automation, and information.[1] Computer science spans theoretical disciplines (such as algorithms, theory of computation, information theory, and automation) to practical disciplines (including the design and implementation of hardware and software).[2][3][4] Computer science is generally considered an area of academic research and distinct from computer programming.[5]
```

Comment: `if (p=0)` should be `if (p==0)`.

Comment: You also never update `i`, so the for loop inside the while never runs.

Comment: yea you are right but thats not the only thing is wrong cause i changed it a while back but i forgot to change it here sry

Comment: Right off the too, `argv[1]` is used without confirming that `argc >= 2`... ALWAYS check data before using it...

Comment: @GiorgosZigouris Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/73183214/16835308

Comment: i found that the problem is strtok . It doenst get the string correct it gets only 3 letters or less and i cant understand why

Answer (score 2):

1. Check if `fopen` succeeds.

```
FILE *file=fopen(argv[1],"r");
if(!file) {
  perror("File opening failed");
  return 1;
}
```

2. `strtok` does not allocate new memory.

`strtok` returns a pointer into the string it is tokenizing, `line`. You're storing pointers to `line` in `words`. `line` is a buffer which gets reused every time `fgets` is called. Every time you read a line, the contents of `line` change, and so does the words pointed to by `words`.

For example, if you're given...

```
The quick brown fox
jumped over the lazy grey dog.
```

Your first iteration would be have line and words like so...

```
line = "The0quick0brown0fox\n"
words  0^  1^    2^    3^
```

`strtok` inserts nulls into the string to separate the tokens, here represented with 0. `words[0]` is "The", `words[1]` is "quick", and so on.

```
line = "jumped0over0the0lazy0grey0dog.\n"
words  0^  1^    2^    3^
       4^     5^   6^  7^   8^   9^
```

`words[4]` is now "jumped", but so is `words[0]`. `words[1]` is "ed". `words[2]` is "r", and so on.

Instead, [copy the word](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strdup) before putting a pointer to it in `words`.

```
if (p=0){
  words[i]=strdup(word);
  wordcount[i]++;
}
```

This technique of reading lines into a buffer and then copying the parts you need is a common way of reading and parsing files.

3. Check what you're comparing.

```
            for (int j=0;j<i;j++){
                if (strcmp(words[i],word)==0){
                    p=1;
                    wordcount[j]++;
                    break;
                } 
            }
```

The intent is to check if you've already seen the word before. You're looping over `j`, but you're comparing against `words[i]`. `words[i]`, at this point, is an empty string. It will be like you never saw the word.

Instead, compare with `words[j]`.

4. Don't walk off the end of the array.

You always increment `i` even if you don't add to `wordcount`. This means `i` is a count of the number of words seen, *not* a count of the length of `words`.

Once you see a word twice, `for (int j=0; j < i; j++) {` will walk off the end of `words`.

Instead, only increment `i` when you see a new word. `i` is a bad variable name and should only be used for counters. It is the next index to use in `words`. Use something descriptive like `next_words_idx`.

5. Strip newlines.

If you have...

```
one two three
one two
```

...there are two twos; `"two"` and `"two\n"`. You need to remove the trailing newlines to have them match.

Comment: @GiorgosZigouris In the for loop you have `if (strcmp(words[i],word)==0){` I think you should be checking `words[j]`.

Comment: @GiorgosZigouris Since at that point `words[i]` will always be blank, `if (strcmp(words[i],word)==0)` will never be true. Every word will be considered a new word. Seems like that's what's happening.

Comment: @GiorgosZigouris You always increment `i` even if you don't add to `words`. That means you can walk off the end of `words`. Try `printf("i: %d, j: %d, %s, %s\n", next_words, j, words[j], word);` to see. `i` is a bad variable name, it should only be used as an iterator. Use something like `next_words_idx`.